# Adobe CS5/AS3 - No "Actions - Movie Clip" tab for my movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash-cs5

I'm writing an Escape the Room game in Flash CS5 / Actionscript 3 (I've written several before) and I have a problem that I've never encountered before. I have two movie clip objects on my escape door movie clip. A doorknob and a keyhole. The doorknob has an "Actions - Movie Clip" tab but the keyhole only has an "Actions" tab with the message "In ActionScript 3.0, code cannot be placed directly on objects. Please select a frame or use the Code Snippets panel to apply code to the current selection on stage."

The two movie clips (instances of two graphics) are in the exact same layer and frame and have identical properties.

I know I'm missing something obvious here and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Adding some screenshots to illustrate:

As you can see below, Doorknob is in the items layer and has an "Actions - Movie Clip tab".

[Doorknob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJeZi.png)

Yet, as you can see below, Keyhole, in the same layer, only has an "Actions" tab.

[Keyhole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDcda.png)

They are both movie clips.

Thanks!

Comment: AS3 cannot be placed on objects. Doorknob is probably at a locked layer so instead of the object you select the frame where AS3 actually can be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That doesn't seem to be the case so I added some screenshots to help illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, my previous games were using AS2. I will publish this one with AS2 and I will need to learn AS3 going forward, thanks to everyone who read my question and for Organis's reply.